# Lodash doesn't work with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash

I get an issue using `lodash` with `NPM`.

My code :

```
var _ = require('lodash');
console.log(_.chunk(['1','2','3','4'], 3));
```

Response : `_.chunk is not a function`

Lodash version : `latest : 4.17.4`

Comment: `[ [ '1', '2', '3' ], [ '4' ] ]` works fine.

Comment: I just tried to install over npm all worked correctly. It's not the code, but i think the install paths. You may not have lodash in node_modules directory where file that runs code located. Check that. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk he would get an error about property `chunk` not found on `undefined` if the module did not load.

Comment: What module loader are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The example you have included is syntactically correct. I would suggest that you make sure that the package is installed correctly.

```
$ npm i -g npm
$ npm i --save lodash
```